# Error while deploying flexipages xml

Tags: lightning, deployment, lightning-apps, package.xml, flexipages

Am facing issue while deploying lightning page related changes to other org using [flexipage]xml file.

> Error: All Component Failures:
>   1.  flexipages/APTS_Quote_Record.flexipage -- Error: The facet Facet-49b51294-e133-47b0-ae7c-c9c78c9c7c10 is defined by a component
>   in the FlexiPage but not actually used.

Thanks!

Comment: are you able to provide the xml of the flexipage?

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the similar issue today while deploying changes related to account lightning page. We have removed one *history tab* from the lightning page. I have added the changes that shows only the removal of history tab. But later we found that metadata also retrieves some kind of metadata as well and *the error is resolved after including this as well as part of the changes.*

below is the metadata :

```xml
<itemInstances>
   <componentInstance>
      <componentInstanceProperties>
         <name>body</name>
         <value>Facet-5b1625a8-4cf5-499c-a66e-675b494125f4</value>
      </componentInstanceProperties>
      <componentInstanceProperties>
         <name>title</name>
         <value>Standard.Tab.analytics</value>
      </componentInstanceProperties>
      <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
   </componentInstance>
</itemInstances>
```